# Raspberry: No internet but SSH working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, system-administration

I reinstalled my Raspberry, and I can access it with SSH, but it can't go outside of the router. How to debug it?

Modell: Raspberry Pi2 B+
OS: Raspbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ip a 
to show your IP
netstat -nr 
to check your Gateway is your Router.
traceroute 8.8.8.8
to see if routing looks ok.

cat /etc/resolv.conf
to see what nameserver is defined.

Although having said all this, you question isn't probably a good one for stackoverflow and you should be googling around something like 'connect raspbian to the internet'  or 'raspbian network setup'

Comment: Thank you. The resolv.conf was empty. I added nameserver 192.168.1.1 and nameserver 8.8.8.8 and now it's working. But after restart te resolv.conf will regenerate itself and will be empty again. Why?

Comment: try removing the request dns-nameservers from /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf